# Is it possible to build a conda package for a subset of files in a Github Repo?

Tags: python, git, build, anaconda, conda

What I want to do is to create a conda package for just one dataset (maybe also its test suite, but everything in one folder) in a [github repo](https://github.com/open-source-economics/taxdata), which currently hosts several datasets and related processing scripts.

I'm very new to conda package, but it seems to me that conda packages are build based on an entire github repo, because the meta.yaml in a recipe only requires a [github url](http://conda-test.pydata.org/docs/build_tutorials/pkgs.html). Would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You could apply a patch that deletes some of the files. You could also specify in your build script to only copy some of the files over. What do you want to happen when the users installs this package?

Comment: I want users to get the dataset and be able to run a few tests on the dataset. So specify the files in the build script would do?

Comment: Where do you want the files to be copied when the user installs the package?